# Is there a way to display text when a specific radio is clicked with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a text field display with this string "Correct" appear below the radio if the correct radio has been clicked.

Here is what I have for the structure

```
      <div id="question2">
        <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what  charaters?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a"/>
        <label>[]</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b"/>
        <label>;;</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="c"/>
        <label>{}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="d"/>
        <label>()</label>
      </div>
```

I'm hoping there is a way to do this using CSS but I haven't been able to find much for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can think of one way, how you can do it with CSS, but it's really not a good idea, just use JavaScript (at least)

Comment: Just FYI.. the answer you chose will show the correct and wrong answers simply by looking at the source code.  I'm not saying my answer is better, but you did ask for a CSS only solution.  If you check the answer I provided, you can accomplish what you want with pure css without revealing your answers in the direct HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda not very nice solution but can be usable to some certain extend :)

Hope this helps :)

```css
input[type="radio"] + label + span {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label + span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="question2">
  <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what charaters?</div>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a" />
  <label>[]</label><span><br/>Wrong answer.</span>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b" />
  <label>;;</label><span><br/>Wrong answer.</span>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="c" />
  <label>{}</label><span><br/>Correct answer.</span>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="d" />
  <label>()</label><span><br/>Wrong answer.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to work. Although I'm having trouble understanding why it works. I see that input[type="radio"]:checked means that this will display when the radio is clicked. I don't quite understand what  display: block !important; means.

Comment: Yes. input[type="radio"]:checked + label + span means that the span tag will display when the radio is clicked. Actually you can remove the !important in the display: block !important; Just use display: block; is enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: You can do this in CSS!

You can achieve this with CSS like so:

```css
input[value="c"]:checked ~ #feedback_box:after {
  content: "correct!"
}
```

```html
 <div id="question2">
        <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what  charaters?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a"/>
        <label>[]</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b"/>
        <label>;;</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="c"/>
        <label>{}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="d"/>
        <label>()</label>
   <p id="feedback_box"></p>
      </div>
```

---

I'm not sure that you can do this in CSS, but I highly doubt it has the desired capabilities to optimally perform the task. You can add a class to the correct radio button and add event listeners to all of them that trigger when clicked. When clicked, they then display a message, "correct". (note that my way of inserting the message is not optimal, you can use your own way).

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("correct"), function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        element.parentElement.innerHTML += "<br>correct";
    });
});
```

```html
      <div id="question2">
        <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what  charaters?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a"/>
        <label>[]</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b"/>
        <label>;;</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" class="correct" value="c"/>
        <label>{}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="d"/>
        <label>()</label>
      </div>
```

The code above does a `forEach` loop over all the elements that have the class name `correct` (notice I added that on a radio button) and then adds a listener to them. Once a user clicks on them, it appends `"<br>correct"` to the parent's `innerHTML` (not optimal).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non adjacent sibling selector '~' to accomplish what you want if it's a pure CSS solution you're looking for. Notice I did add an id to each of your inputs to make the selectors simpler, though you could accomplish the same thing by checking value.

**CSS Explained:**

When the radio button ID'd `q2` belonging to the parent ID'd `question2` has the property 'checked' (note the pseudo selector `:checked`) the non-adjacent sibling matching the ID `question2_status` will have the content 'Correct' appended to it's `:before` pseudo selector. `~` is the reference to the non-adjacent sibling, meaning that it shares the same parent, but isn't directly the previous or next child of it. This is used because the container for the result is below all the options.  Therefore you can apply this same logic to any of your questions regardless of the correct answer's position in the list.

```css
#question2 #q2c:checked ~ #question2_status:before {
  content: 'Correct';
}
```

```html
<div id="question2">
        <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what  charaters?</div>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2a" value="a"/>
        <label>[]</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2b" value="b"/>
        <label>;;</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2c" value="c"/>
        <label>{}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2d" value="d"/>
        <label>()</label>
        <div id='question2_status'></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This is actually a great way to do this! I stand corrected

Answer (score 0):

i think you can accomplish your goal using javascript.

use the onclick attribute for each radio button. then write two javascript functions (correct and wrong). use a div element for display the output of those javascript functions. here

note that there are two image files in the root directory named correct.jpg and wrong.jpg to display the right mark or wrong mark. you can use a text instead of images. hope this helps. thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                function correct()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("displayer").innerHTML="<img src='correct.jpg'/> ";

                    }
                function wrong()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("displayer").innerHTML="<img src='wrong.jpg'/> ";
                    }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="question2">
            <div class="question">A JavaScript object is wrapped by what  charaters?</div>  <br/>
            1) <input type="radio" onclick="wrong();" id="btn1" name="question2" value="a"/>  
            <label>  [ ]</label>  <br/>
            2) <input type="radio" onclick="wrong();" id="btn2" name="question2" value="b"/>
            <label>  ; ;</label> <br/>
            3) <input type="radio" onclick="correct();" id="btn3" name="question2" value="c"/>
            <label>  { }</label> <br/>
            4) <input type="radio" onclick="wrong();" id="btn4" name="question2" value="d"/>
            <label> ( )</label> <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="displayer"> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```